# Is there any way to get permissions until revoked with phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect?

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm using phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect and it is working well (I can login the user and query the API) but the session that I'm getting has expiration. I wonder if is there any way to get the access token without expiration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to request `offline_access` in addition to the other permissions your app requests.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: Please be sure to accept this answer so the question doesn't show up on the unanswered list.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

if you use this code:

> FB.init({ appId: "app_id", nativeInterface: PG.FB });

in your app, then the FB login expires when the **native** facebook app on your phone is disconnected. If you stay connected in this app then your app wont disconnect either.